# My program doesn't align the columns as It should [C language]

Tags: c

I'm trying to finish my program but it kinda doesn't show what it should.

This is the `main` code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int happynum(int num);
#define MAXCOLUM 4

int main()
{
int num, liminf, limsup, cont=0, cont2=0, col, hnum, contc=0, ch;

   do{
        //DIGITANDO EL RANGO
      do{
        system("cls");
         printf("Enter lower limit: ",161);
         scanf("%d",&liminf);


         if ( liminf <= 0 )
         {
            printf("value must be up to 0.\n");
            system("pause");
         }

      }while ( liminf <= 0 );

      do{
            system("cls");
         printf("Enter upper limit: ");
         scanf("%5d",&limsup);

         if ( limsup <= 0 )
         {
            printf("value must be up to 0.\n");
            system("pause");
         }

      }while ( limsup <= 0 );

      // VALIDANDO EL RANGO

      if ( liminf >= limsup )
      {
         printf("Incorrect range.\n",130);
         getch();
      }

   }while ( liminf >= limsup);

     do{
            system("cls");
            printf("Enter # of columns to show the happy numbers (max 4): \n");
            scanf("%d", &col);

            if (col > 4 || col < 0)
            {
                printf("Enter again the # of columns \n");
            }
        }while (col > 4 || col < 0);

    system("cls");
    printf("Happy numbers between the range [%d,%d]: \n",163,liminf,limsup);

    for (num = liminf; num<=limsup; num++)
    {
        hnum = happynum(num);

       if (hnum== 1)
        {
        printf("%.d F\n", num);
        cont++;
        }
            else {
                printf("%.d \n", num);
                cont++;
            }


                if (contc < col)
                {
                    printf("\t");
                    contc++;
                } else
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    cont2++;
                    contc=1;
                }
                if (cont2>=20)
                {
                   cont2=0;
                   do{

            printf("Press enter to continue");
            ch=getch();
            system("cls");
            }while(ch!=13);

                /*printf("Press Enter to Continue");
                while( getchar() != '\n' );*/
                }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the function:

```
int happynum(int num)
{
int i,dig,sum=0;

while(num!=89 && num!=1)
{
   sum=0;
   while(num>0)
    {
    dig=num%10;
    num=num/10;
    sum=sum+(dig*dig);
    }
  num=sum;
}
    if (num == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the output should be something like this:

```
happy numbers between range [1,50]:

1 F  21
2    22
3    23 F
4    24
5    25 
6    26
7 F  27
8    28 F
9    29
10 F 30
11   31 F
12   32 F
13 F 33
14   34
15   35
16   36
17   37
18   38
19 F 39
20   40

Press enter to keep showing numbers...

happy numbers between range [1,50]:

41
42
43
44 F
45
46
47
48
49 F
50
```

But the output that shows it's this:

```
1 F
        2
        3
        4

5
        6
        7 F

8
        9
        10 F

11
        12
        13 F

14
        15
        16

17
        18
        19 F

20
        21
        22

23 F
        24
        25

26
        27
        28 F

29
        30
        31 F

32 F
        33
        34

35
        36
        37

38
        39
        40

41
        42
        43

44 F
        45
        46

47
        48
        49 F

50
```

Please check out the code and let me know If there's something I'm missing or something its wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: `%.d` is not a valid format specifier.  The `.` should be followed by an `*` or a decimal integer precision value.  Otherwise the code is incomplete and cannot be compiled without `happynum()` so it is not possible for anyone to verify a solution.  The input prompts are in Spanish, it would be helpful if you included the example input that generated the results you describe, so that non Spanish speakers might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
printf("%.d F\n", num);  //you should remove the \n here
printf("%.d \n", num);   //you should remove the \n here
```

You should remove the \n from these printf above, because you are intending to print all linebreaks \n in this scope below:

```
            if (contc < col)
            {
                printf("\t");
                contc++;
            } else
            {
                printf("\n");
                cont2++;
                contc=1; //you should change it to contc =0
            }
```

And, contc=1 in this scope, is wrong. It should be contc =0 because the contc starts from 0 at the beginning, not 1.

After these changes, I have already debugged it in my compiler and the result is just what you want.

**THIS IS THE FULL FIX:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int happynum(int num);
#define MAXCOLUM 4

int main()
{
    int num, liminf, limsup, cont = 0, cont2 = 0, col, hnum, contc = 0, ch,c;

    do
    {
        //DIGITANDO EL RANGO
        do
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("Enter lower limit: ");
            scanf("%d", &liminf);


            if (liminf <= 0)
            {
                printf("value must be up to 0.\n");
                system("pause");
            }
        }
        while (liminf <= 0);

        do
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("Enter upper limit: ");
            scanf("%5d", &limsup);

            if (limsup <= 0)
            {
                printf("value must be up to 0.\n");
                system("pause");
            }
        }
        while (limsup <= 0);

        // VALIDANDO EL RANGO

        if (liminf >= limsup)
        {
            printf("Incorrect range.\n");
            getchar();
        }
    }
    while (liminf >= limsup);

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Enter # of columns to show the happy numbers (max 4): \n");
        scanf("%d", &col);

        if (col > 4 || col < 0)
        {
            printf("Enter again the # of columns \n");
        }
    }
    while (col > 4 || col < 0);

    system("cls");
    printf("Happy numbers between the range [%d,%d]: \n", liminf, limsup);

    for (num = liminf; num <= limsup; num++)
    {
        hnum = happynum(num);

        if (hnum == 1)
        {
            printf("%.d F", num);
            cont++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%.d ", num);
            cont++;
        }


        if (contc < col-1)
        {
            printf("\t");
            contc++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
            cont2++;
            contc = 0;
        }
        if (cont2 >= 20)
        {
            cont2 = 0;
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
            do
            {
                printf("Press enter to continue");
                ch = getchar();
                system("cls");
            }
            while (ch != '\r'&&ch!='\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


int happynum(int num)
{
    int i, dig, sum = 0;

    while (num != 89 && num != 1)
    {
        sum = 0;
        while (num > 0)
        {
            dig = num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
            sum = sum + (dig * dig);
        }
        num = sum;
    }
    if (num == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I used `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');` to flush the input buffer so that `while (ch != '\r'&&ch!='\n');` can detect input properly.

(your original code `while (ch !=13);`does not work proper for me

Comment: Thank you so much, I did that but my outputs doesn't show the code with  the # of columns entered.

Comment: It works! But what I tried to say is that, for example, I enter 2 columns but the code keeps showing in 3 columns. Like, never considering the `col` value.

Comment: @aticboy sorry for the latecoming reply. I will debug it now.

Comment: It shows 5 columns, I think it's because the numbers are showing up in secuence like:
` 1, 2, 3`